# How to play YouTube videos in mpv?

Tags: youtube, mpv

I sometime do that on the Linux desktop - but on the phone I cannot do it. What I see is exactly what is presented in [this video](https://www.reddit.com/r/mpv/comments/y2rxo5/how_can_i_play_youtube_videos_in_mpv_android/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) on *reddit*. Adding the video url to *mpv* does nothing. [The answer](https://www.reddit.com/r/mpv/comments/y2rxo5/comment/is4kyua/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) seems to be that `yt-dlp` has to be installed.

To do that I have followed [these](https://www.reddit.com/r/youtubedl/comments/10d2knp/comment/j4moxfh/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) instructions, installed Termux and then did:

```
pkg up
pkg install python
pkg install ffmpeg
python3 -m pip install --upgrade yt-dlp
```

Then, in order to make mpv work with `yt-dlp`, I followed the instruction [here](https://www.funkyspacemonkey.com/replace-youtube-dl-with-yt-dlp-how-to-make-mpv-work-with-yt-dlp): entered `mpv` advanced settings, selected the option to edit `mpv.conf`, and pasted `script-opts=ytdl_hook-ytdl_path=/usr/bin/yt-dlp`.

But those are settings for Linux. Should they work for Android? Why don't they? I see the same as before, `mpv` does nothing after adding the url.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not the first time once I post a question I find the answer :)

[This](https://github.com/mpv-android/mpv-android/issues/111) `mpv-android` issue complains exactly about that, linking to [this](https://github.com/mpv-android/mpv-android/pull/58) about integration with `youtube-dl`. There, a link to a `mpv-android` `apk` file which has that integration is available. Uninstalling default release of mpv and installing *that* version of `mpv-android`, we can see that its advanced settings include a new entry to install `youtub-dl` or `yt-dlp`.

[image]

There is a limited amount of GUI options in mpv, but playback in background is one of them:

[image]